# Analyze a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on an old project and I need to make some changes. I came across a query in the middle of c# code which I couldn't realize how it worked.

This is the query:

```
select 
   case 
      when f.charge_status_id =3 or f.charge_status_id =4 then 'sold' 
      when f.charge_status_id =2 then 'reserved'
      when f.charge_status_id =1 then 'remaining '
   End,
   f.mobile_company_type_id, f.company_batchid,
   sum(f.countt)  
from 
   (select  
       t.mobile_company_type_id, t.company_batchid, t.charge_status_id,
       count(t.serial_no) as countt
    from 
       css_charge_codes t 
    where 
       t.company_batchid <> '0'
    group by 
       t.mobile_company_type_id, t.company_batchid, t.charge_status_id) f 
group by 
    charge_status_id, f.mobile_company_type_id, f.company_batchid
order by 
    f.mobile_company_type_id, f.company_batchid, f.charge_status_id
```

and the columns of table "css_charge_codes" are like this:

```
Mobile_company_type_Id,serial_no,amount,file_number,charge_code,    
help_desk,PAN,charge_status_ID,batch_ID,Company_batchID
```

When I run this query with PlSql, it returns a table with 4 columns:

```
   CASEWHENF.CHARGE_STATUS_ID=3OR,MOBILE_COMPANY_TYPE_ID,batch_ID,SUM(F.COUNTT)
```

can any one help me?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Well, I don't understand what "f" and "t" are. and what is the "countt" value.

Comment: Does this query even work?

Answer (score 1):

"f" and "t" are aliases for datasources. You can also write "as f" or "as t".

"f" is used to get a reference for the subquery and "t" is simply the alias for the datasource css_charge_codes.

```
  count(t.serial_no) as countt
```

This counts all searial_nos in the query and gives the result the alias "countt" (aggregate function) over the distinct groups of:

```
group by 
charge_status_id, f.mobile_company_type_id, f.company_batchid
```

This "countt" can then be referenced from the outer query => "f.countt"

Answer (score 0):

`countt` is an alias for the result of this sql:

```
 select  
   t.mobile_company_type_id, t.company_batchid, t.charge_status_id,
   count(t.serial_no)
```

`t` is an alias for table `css_charge_codes`

and `f` is an alias for the result of this sql:

```
select  
   t.mobile_company_type_id, t.company_batchid, t.charge_status_id,
   count(t.serial_no) as countt
from 
   css_charge_codes t 
where 
   t.company_batchid <> '0'
group by 
   t.mobile_company_type_id, t.company_batchid, t.charge_status_id
```